# Converting an input audio file to a monophonic FLAC file

Tags: c#, audio, cyclomatic-complexity

I have the following method which basically converts an input audio file to a monophonic FLAC file.

Now I am getting *Member has cyclomatic complexity of 21 (105%)* message in Visual Studio, while I've taken care of improving it as in the beginning it was longer, now there's not much I can remove from it as it pretty much fulfills my needs.

Should I just ignore this warning ?

```
private static void Convert(string inputFile, string outputFile, IProgress<double> progress = null)
{
    if (inputFile == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("inputFile");
    if (outputFile == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("outputFile");
    int stream = 0;
    int mixer = 0;
    try
    {
        stream = Bass.BASS_StreamCreateFile(inputFile, 0, 0,
            BASSFlag.BASS_STREAM_DECODE | BASSFlag.BASS_SAMPLE_FLOAT | BASSFlag.BASS_STREAM_PRESCAN);
        if (stream == 0) throw new BassException("Could not create stream");
        var info = Bass.BASS_ChannelGetInfo(stream);
        if (info == null) throw new BassException("Could not retrieve stream info");
        var freq = info.freq;
        mixer = BassMix.BASS_Mixer_StreamCreate(freq, 1,
            BASSFlag.BASS_MIXER_END | BASSFlag.BASS_SAMPLE_FLOAT | BASSFlag.BASS_STREAM_DECODE);
        if (mixer == 0) throw new BassException("Could not create mixer");
        bool addChannel = BassMix.BASS_Mixer_StreamAddChannel(mixer, stream, BASSFlag.BASS_MIXER_NORAMPIN);
        if (!addChannel) throw new BassException("Could not add stream to mixer");
        long getLength = Bass.BASS_ChannelGetLength(stream);
        if (getLength == -1) throw new BassException("Could not get channel length");
        var encoder = new EncoderFLAC(mixer)
        {
            Force16Bit = true,
            FLAC_Verify = true,
            OutputFile = outputFile
        };
        if (!encoder.Start(null, IntPtr.Zero, false))
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Could not start encoder");
        const int samples = 65536;
        const int bytes = (samples * sizeof(float)) | (int)BASSData.BASS_DATA_FLOAT;
        var buffer = new float[samples];
        long bytesRead = 0;
        while (Bass.BASS_ChannelIsActive(mixer) == BASSActive.BASS_ACTIVE_PLAYING)
        {
            int getData = Bass.BASS_ChannelGetData(mixer, buffer, bytes);
            bytesRead += getData;
            if (progress != null) progress.Report(1.0d / getLength * bytesRead);
        }
        encoder.Stop();
        if (getLength / sizeof(short) != bytesRead)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Output length not equal to input length");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Conversion failed", ex);
    }
    finally
    {
        if (stream != 0) Bass.BASS_StreamFree(stream);
        if (mixer != 0) Bass.BASS_StreamFree(mixer);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your code would become much simpler and more readable if you encapsulated all the BASS-related functionality from into separate types.

Something like:

```
class Stream
{
    private readonly int handle;

    // add overload that supports setting offset and lenght, if you need that
    public Stream(string inputFile, BASSFlag flags)
    {
        handle = BASS_StreamCreateFile(inputFile, 0, 0, flags);

        if (handle == 0)
            throw new BassException("Could not create stream");
    }

    public ChannelInfo GetInfo()
    {
        var result = Bass.BASS_ChannelGetInfo(stream);

        if (result == null)
            throw new BassException("Could not retrieve stream info");

        return result;
    }

    // etc.
}
```

This would simplify the start of your code to just:

```
Stream stream = new Stream(inputFile,
    BASSFlag.BASS_STREAM_DECODE | BASSFlag.BASS_SAMPLE_FLOAT | BASSFlag.BASS_STREAM_PRESCAN);
var info = stream.GetInfo();
```